# DataGridView should not acccept duplicate ID with first and last name

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here is my code should not accept duplicate rows in DataGridView but in my code, it's excepting:

> should not accept duplicate rows [THis is my datagridview it's not taking duplicate ID's but taking remaining fields to duplicate it should not duplicate filename, Lastname, and profession also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbbQG.png)

[I need output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ze1.png)

```
namespace Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable
{
    public partial class Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable : Form
    {
        public Bind_DataGridView_Using_DataTable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string idText = IDTxt.Text.Trim();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idText) && int.TryParse(idText, out int idValue))
            {
                if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0)
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(idValue, fisrtTxt.Text.Trim(), SurNameTxt.Text.Trim(), ProfesTxt.Text.Trim());
                    //table.AcceptChanges();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                    cleatTxts();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Person Id already Exist");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Person Id should not be empty && must be a valid int value";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the pictures… I do not understand why you want 2 GHK SRYU DHGHJ …and… 4 RTY RYY1 OIO removed? The code is “checking” if the new ID is the same as an existing ID in the table `(table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0` ... and None of the IDs are the same! (1,2,3,4)… All the IDs are different so why would they not be added? If you say the names are the same, then shouldn’t the code be checking for the same names also? You are going to have to figure out some “special” handling as I described in  your previous question about this.

Comment: requirement is like that not only ID remainig column values also unique it should not repeat. please help me on this

Comment: It appears you need to add checks on the first and last name after the check on the ID is made. If the ID is duplicated, then it doesn’t matter what the name is… do not add. If the ID is not duplicated, then you need to check the first and last names, if a duplicate name is found then don’t add, otherwise add the new id and name.

Comment: I am new to this can you help me do this???

Comment: Add an additional check after the ID check… something like… `(table.Select("FirstName = " + fisrtTxt.Text.Trim() + "AND LastName = " + SurNameTxt.Text.Trim()) ).Length == 0`

Comment: This wont work for other field getting error cannot find name

Comment: I can not see what code is causing the error so I can only guess that one or both of the field names in my comment do not match the name of the column in the table the code is using. From the pictures, the first name is “FirstName” and the last name is “LastName,”… check the spelling. Since you did not update the code, this is speculation.

Comment: if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0 || (table.Select("FirstName= " + fisrtTxt.Text.Trim())).Length == 0) here it is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is difficult about this. Use two `if` statements, not one compound `if` statement… `If` ID is NOT duplicated then, `if` first AND last names are not duplicated then add the row. You need to keep in mind, that if the ID IS a duplicate, then there is no need to check the names.

```
if ((table.Select("Id = " + idValue)).Length == 0) {
  if ((table.Select("FirstName = '" + firstTxt.Text.Trim() +
                    "' AND LastName = '" + SurNameTxt.Text.Trim() + "'")).Length == 0) {
     // add  the row 
  }
}

Note the single quote " ' " before/after the text box values.
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct table by columns like this

```
table = table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new 
    { 
        FirstName = r.Field<string>("FirstName"), 
        LastName = r.Field<string>("LastName"), 
        Profession = r.Field<string>("Profession") 
    })
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Can you try this?

`table = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { FirstName = r.Field<string>("FirstName"), LastName = r.Field<string>("LastName"), Profession = r.Field<string>("Profession") }).Select(group => group.First()).CopyToDataTable();`